# Should templates be in blueprint template folders or the global template folder?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I see that there's two ways to structure templates in the project.  Templates can be stored in the `templates/` folder in the blueprint, or each blueprint has a folder inside a global templates folder.  What's the difference between the two?  Why should I use one over the other?

```
app/
    blueprint1/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        templates/
    blueprint2/
        __init__.py
        views.py
        templates/
    templates/  # Global templates folder
```

```
app/
    blueprint1/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    blueprint2/
        __init__.py
        views.py
    templates/  # Global templates folder
        blueprint1/
        blueprint2/
```

Comment: Personally,  I would go with option 2, as everything is at one place.

Comment: I use the first, especially when blueprints are used to serve up radically different cotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are equivalent in terms of what Flask sees, its Jinja loader combines the blueprint and global folders.  Blueprint templates are treated as default sources, and the global source overrides those.  Typically, blueprint templates are only useful if you're writing an extension that others will install and override, it doesn't provide anything if you're just using them internally.  Note that you need to use the same folder structure within the blueprint and global folders, otherwise you will see unexpected conflicts since the loader overlays the folders directly, not by blueprint name.

```
project/
    package/
        __init__.py
        blueprint1/
            __init__.py
            templates/
                blueprint1/
                    page.html  # default
        templates/
            blueprint1/
                page.html  # overrides blueprint
```